# Regex to count number of ampersands in a string, efficiently. Iterating through string not an option

Tags: c#, regex

We're trying to count number of ampersands in a string efficiently using Regex. I know I can count them, by iterating, I need it in Regex form due a framework requirement.

Is there someone who could provide a regex that just counts internally? That is it doesn't actually do any matching other than that. Or minimal matching and saving of the matches.

**Let me clarify, counting is not an option, we need a Regex. Put simply, I have a string I read from a file, I dynamically pass that to a library I don't have code for. And therefore need a regex**

Comment: I'm no expert in regex, but I want to help anyway. I would do it like this `"my#string#is#this".Split('#').Count() - 1` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your framework requirement is necessitating the use of regex, but here's a simple linq solution in case it's of value to you.

```
string str = "asas&fgdf&rete&";
int numOfAmpersands = str.Count(c => c == '&');

Console.WriteLine(numOfAmpersands); //prints 3
```

**EDIT**

Regex version:

```
string str = "asas&fgdf&rete&";
Regex r = new Regex("&");
int regexMatchCount = r.Matches(str).Count;
```

Comment: Updated my question, cannot use regular counting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this. you can simply do

```
string source = "foo & bar & bob & alice";
int ampersand_count = source.Split('&').Length - 1;
```

Comment: It's an awfully slow way for counting a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Counting is explicitly one of the things that a regular expression cannot do...